# How can I use tail utility to view a log file that is frequently recreated

Tags: bash, file, tail

I need a solution in creating a script to tail a log file that is recreated (with the same name) after it reaches a certain size.

Using "`tail -f`" causes the tailing to stop when the file is recreated/rotated.

What I would like to do is create a script that would tail the file and after it reaches 100 lines for example, then restart the command...  Or even better to restart the command when the file is recreated?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 23):

Yes!  Use this (the retry will make tail retry when the file doesn't exist or is otherwise inaccessible rather than just failing - such as potentially when you are changing files):

```
tail -f --retry <filename>
```

OR

```
tail --follow=name --retry
```

OR

```
tail -F <filename>
```

Comment: ~> tail -f --follow=name --retry /logs/logs/log.log
tail: cannot open input

Comment: It looks like you have `/logs` in there twice.  Is that intentional? If that file doesn't exist or you don't have permissions, you will get an error.  However, with `--retry` it will keep trying until the file exists or you have permissions to it.  Try it out with a test file in the current directory first.

Comment: yes that was intentional. This is the directory where my logs are stored. Unfortunately this version of tail doesn't support -F or --follow=name. I'm trying to find another way to do this with a script.

Comment: OS X tail doesn't support the `--retry` option.

Comment: On macOS, you can install and use the GNU version of `tail` easily with [homebrew](https://brew.sh). Install with: `brew install coreutils`. Use with: `gtail -f --follow=name --retry <filename>` (The gnu utils are prefixed with `g` in order not to conflict with the macOS core tools.)

Answer (score 2):

try running

```
watch "tail -f" yourfile.log
```

Comment: watch is unavailable on the system i'm running unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

If tail -F is **not** available, and you are trying to recover from **logrotate**, you may add the `copytruncate` option to your `logrotate.d/` spec file so instead of creating a new file each time after rotation, the file is kept and truncated, while a copy is rotated out.

This way the old file handle continues to point to the new `(truncated)` log file where new logs are appended.

Note that there may be some loss of data during this `copy-truncate` process.

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont have a tail that support all the features and because you dont have watch you could use a simple script that loop indefinitely to execute the tail.

```
#!/bin/bash 

PID=`mktemp`
while true;
do
  [ -e "$1" ] && IO=`stat -c %i "$1"`
  [ -e "$1" ] && echo "restarting tail" && { tail -f "$1" 2> /dev/null & echo $! > $PID; }

  # as long as the file exists and the inode number did not change
  while [[ -e "$1" ]] && [[ $IO = `stat -c %i "$1"` ]]
  do
     sleep 0.5
  done
  [ ! -z $PID ] && kill `cat $PID` 2> /dev/null && echo > $PID
  sleep 0.5
done 2> /dev/null
rm -rf $PID
```

You might want to use trap to cleanly exit this script. This is up to you.

Basicaly, this script check if the inode number (using `stat -c %i "$1"`) change to kill the `tail` command and start a new one when the file is recreated.

Note: you might get rid of the `echo "restarting tail"` which will pollute your output. It was only useful for testing. Also problems might occur if the file is replaced after we check the inode number and before we start the tail process.